# tf.texts_to_sequences start with 0

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am doing label encoding using Encoder using below code. It does encoding but starts with 1 instead of 0. How can I make it to start encoding by 0?

```
label_tokenizer = Tokenizer()
label_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(labels)

training_label_seq = np.array(label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_labels))
validation_label_seq = np.array(label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(validation_labels))
```

Below code shows that it is starting from 1:

```
label_tokenizer.word_index

{'credit': 10,
 'deduction': 9,
 'notification': 6,
 'notificationcredit': 4,
 'notificationfailed': 8,
 'notificationfinancial': 1,
 'notificationimportant': 2,
 'notificationreminder': 7,
 'notificationsuccess': 11,
 'otp': 3,
 'personal': 5,
 'promotion': 12,
 'reminder': 13}
```

Purpose is, I want to use these labels in training the tensorflow. With labels encodings starting with 1, it is giving me error: `Received a label value of 13 which is outside the valid range of [0, 13)`
Here is the model definition . For now to make things work I have added +1 to the total classes in last layer:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=max_words, output_dim=64, input_length=input_dim),
  keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(64)), #, return_sequences=True
  keras.layers.Dense(y_train.shape[1]+1, activation="softmax")])
```

Comment: I have an idea, but can u please add your model structure

Comment: I suggest you to do training_label_seq-1 and validation_label_seq-1, in this way the labels star from 0 (also remove '+1' in the last layer)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this this morning using exactly the same variable notation as you... ;D

Marco Cerliani has it right - so, to quote him, simply do:

```py
training_label_seq = np.array(label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_labels)) - 1
validation_label_seq = np.array(label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(validation_labels)) - 1
```

Indeed you need to keep the number of classes as what you intended - so ensure to remove the `+1`:

```py
model = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=max_words, output_dim=64, input_length=input_dim),
  keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(64)), #, return_sequences=True
  keras.layers.Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation="softmax")])
```